# Why are Max and Caroline poor in “2 Broke Girls?”

Tags: plot-explanation, 2-broke-girls

In [*2 Broke Girls*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2_Broke_Girls), Max and Caroline work at the diner, and they do extra jobs (selling cupcakes and other stuff).

So they have two salaries, but even then, they can't afford toilet paper!

How is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure of *where* they are supposed to be located, but you could probably assume a large city in the northeastern US, probably NYC (they may say within the series, I just don't remember).

Cost of living is not cheap in big cities, even with two jobs. With that said, first, they are only working as waitresses in a greasy spoon, so they are not getting paid a lot, and I'm sure tips are even less.

Second, they are trying to save money so as to open/operate a cupcake store. They don't have any money because they don't have much in the first place and they are trying to scrimp and save what they do have the for the store.

Comment: They live in Brooklyn. In other TV shows we see for example someone working as waitress and he can afford many things. That's why I asked the question

Comment: Also, they keep making blunders and buying random stuff here and there, especially in credit card episode.